# Login to router

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication

I have made a simple script for showing data from router, but there is an error :

Failed to load resource

But the location is available. So what could be the real cause of the problem.

```
var xmlhttp = null;
if ( window.ActiveXObject )
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
} 
else 
{
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xmlhttp.open ( "POST", "http://" + routerIP + port + link, true );
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
//base64UserPass in format user:pass
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ( "Authorization", "Basic " + base64UserPass );
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ( "Connection", "close" );

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 )
    {
        document.write ( xmlhttp.responseText );
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert ( "Error ocurred: server not responding!\n" + xmlhttp.responseText );
    }
};

xmlhttp.send ( "" );
```

Comment: Please post code directly here vs. using a link to a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot use AJAX to interact with a different domain.

This is completely impossible.

Comment: Could [xdr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303(v=vs.85).aspx) be used?

Comment: @shagon: Not unless the router sends an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, which it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Also jQuery supports ACD (AJAX Cross Domain). Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (setting "crossDomain")

Comment: That won't work; no sane router will send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.